# Laravel make migration with foreign key failed

Tags: laravel

I have a project named Partner

I need to create `developers` table and two other tables `branches` and `projects`

And every Developer has many branches and has many projects

So I created this migration files:

Developers

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('developers', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('company_name', 100);
        $table->string('responsible_name', 100);
        $table->string('email', 100);
        $table->string('phone', 100);
        $table->string('hotline', 100)->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Branches

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('branches', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->integer('developer_id')->unsigned();
        $table->string('name', 100);
        $table->string('address', 100);
        $table->string('location', 100);
        $table->string('phone', 100);
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->foreign('developer_id')->references('id')->on('developers')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
}
```

Projects

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('projects', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->integer('developer_id')->unsigned();
        $table->string('name', 100);
        $table->string('type', 100);
        $table->string('address', 100);
        $table->string('location', 100);
        $table->string('availability', 100);
        $table->text('payment_plan');
        $table->string('brochure', 100)->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->foreign('developer_id')->references('id')->on('developers')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
}
```

But when I ran `php artisan migrate` I got this error

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `partner`.`branches` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `branches` add constraint `branches_developer_id_foreign` foreign key (`developer_id`) references `developers` (`id`) on delete cascade)
```

What is the wrong with the form of the foreign key?

Comment: `id()` is an alias of [bigInteger()](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/migrations#column-method-bigInteger), your types need to match

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use foreign key in migration without predefine field :

```
$table->foreignId('developer_id')->constrained('developers')->onDelete('cascade');
```

and remove this line :

```
$table->integer('developer_id')->unsigned();
```